# Почему в этом случае не получается вынести стили отдельно?

Tags: javascript, css3

Стили нужно вынести отдельно для :

```
 <div oncontextmenu="return menu(1, event)"; style="height:300px; border:1px solid red; background-color:transprent;"> Кликни правой кнопкой </div>
 <div id="contextMenuId" style="width:200px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border:1px solid #666;   background-color:#CCC; display:none; float:left;">
```

т.е из inline-style сделать хотя бы встроенные ? код просто перестаёт работать

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style> 
     .block{
      width:600px;
      height:300px;
      margin:auto;
     }
     #contextMenuId a,li{
      border:1px solid #fefefe;
      height:20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      width:200px
      text-align: center;
      display:block;
      padding:4px 3px;
     }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="block">
  <div oncontextmenu="return menu(1, event)"; style="height:300px; border:1px solid red; background-color:transprent;"> Кликни правой кнопкой </div>
  <div id="contextMenuId" style="width:200px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border:1px solid #666; background-color:#CCC; display:none; float:left;"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://geyanpeaple.github.io/js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт блокирует **`ПКМ`** и открывает своё контекстное меню

Comment: я не понял: какие стили откуда куда убираются?

Comment: в самом вверху есть инлайн стили прямо в блоке , я выношу их отдельно в теги style но js тупо перестаёт работать , почему то

Comment: имеются ввиду два дива с `<div oncontextmenu` и `<div id="contextMenuId"`?

Comment: да ! те что внутри .block

Comment: на самом деле не код перестает работать, а просто див все еще невидим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в выносе: в *inline* стилях прописан `display:none`, поэтому при выполнении строки

```
menu.style.display = "";
```

Восстанавливалось значение по умолчанию, в конкретном случае `block`.

При переносе в стили - при выполнении этой строки ничего не поменяется, и стиль продолжит брать `display:none`.

Поэтому его надо уставить в значение `block` для показа.

```
menu.style.display = "block";
```

Например:

```js
function defPosition(event) {
  var x = y = 0;
  if (document.attachEvent != null) { // Internet Explorer & Opera
    x = window.event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    y = window.event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
  } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) { // Gecko
    x = event.clientX + window.scrollX;
    y = event.clientY + window.scrollY;
  } else {
    // Do nothing
  }
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

function menu(type, evt) {
  // Блокируем всплывание события contextmenu
  evt = evt || window.event;
  evt.cancelBubble = true;
  // Показываем собственное контекстное меню
  var menu = document.getElementById("contextMenuId");
  var html = "";
  switch (type) {
    case (1):
      html = "<li>webRefferal.com</li>";
      html += "<a href='#'>Первая функция</a>";
      html += "<a href='#'>Вторая функция</a>";
      html += "<a href='#'>Третья функция</a>";
      break;

  }
  // Если есть что показать - показываем
  if (html) {
    menu.innerHTML = html;
    menu.style.top = defPosition(evt).y + "px";
    menu.style.left = defPosition(evt).x + "px";
    menu.style.display = "block";
  }
  // Блокируем всплывание стандартного браузерного меню
  return false;
}

// Закрываем контекстное при клике левой или правой кнопкой по документу
// Функция для добавления обработчиков событий
function addHandler(object, event, handler, useCapture) {
  if (object.addEventListener) {
    object.addEventListener(event, handler, useCapture ? useCapture : false);
  } else if (object.attachEvent) {
    object.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
  } else alert("Add handler is not supported");
}
addHandler(document, "contextmenu", function() {
  document.getElementById("contextMenuId").style.display = "none";
});
addHandler(document, "click", function() {
  document.getElementById("contextMenuId").style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
.block div:first-child {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: transprent;
}
#contextMenuId a,
li {
  border: 1px solid #fefefe;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 3px;
}
#contextMenuId {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div oncontextmenu="return menu(1, event)">Кликни правой кнопкой</div>
  <div id="contextMenuId" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Geyan, эм, а мы когда-то спорили? если убрать js - то сниппет станет нерабочим

Comment: @Geyan, нет, в данном случае это не правильно. Скрипт является неотъемлимой частью примера, и ответ как раз заключается в **изменении** скрипта. Поэтому текст скрипта **должен** быть и в вопросе и в ответе.

Comment: блин !хренова , лан спс

Comment: @Geyan, а что в нем такого, что обязательно ссылкой надо? Тем более ссылка на твой github есть у тебя в профиле

Comment: ну и потому я и хотел спрятать , да в принципе пофигу - лан не буду делать проблему с этого , огромное спасибо , в общем проблема была из за конфликта в js ?

Comment: @Geyan, из-за того, что после выноса: `display` устанавливался из `css` а не был значением свойства. поэтому при изменении его в коде - ничего не менялось на экране - оно как было пустое, так пустым и осталось

Comment: но  я объявлял в блоке без `class и id ` идентификатор и придавал все те же свойства но тщетно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42761/discussion-between-grundy-and-geyan).